# Crystal circuit works in breadboard but not in perfboard

Tags: clock, crystal

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to build a digital clock. My clock generator looks like this:

[circuit http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/855/tempgd.png](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/855/tempgd.png)

It works perfectly on the breadboard, where I can see the LED blinking at 2 Hz. However, when I try to solder it on the perfboard, it blinks much faster. I don't have a way to measure, but I'd say something like 10 Hz.

I tried to mount three times on the breadboard and three times on the perfboard, and always get the same result. I checked and rechecked the connections, and everything seems to be fine. I have no idea where the problem might be. What could be wrong?

**EDIT**

I tried replacing the two 15pF capacitor for two 22pF, but it didn't help. Unfortunately, I don't have access to a oscilloscope to see what's happening inside.

Here are the photos of the circuit. The first one is the component side.

[photo1 http://imageshack.us/a/img405/5062/dsc07884v.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img405/5062/dsc07884v.jpg)

The second one is the soldering side. Please excuse my bad soldering, I'm a beginner, and it's a little messy from all soldering/desoldering. However, I tested all connections and the connections are correct.

[photo2 http://imageshack.us/a/img132/9470/dsc07885l.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img132/9470/dsc07885l.jpg)

Additional question: I'm using a 10K resistor. I saw a similar circuit on the internet that uses a 220K resistor in its place. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I can't quite work out what's supposed to be happening with the oscillator inputs, but one of them is unattached. Floating CMOS inputs love to pick up noise. If it ends up counting noise that would explain the behaviour. Do you have an oscilliscope you can put on Q0 and see if you get a nice square wave at the right frequency? Can you post a picture of the solder side of your assembled perfboard?

Comment: This is probably due to capacitance on the breadboard. The connections act as little capacitors, so you can try increasing those 15 pF capacitors a bit.

Comment: Changing the capacitors didn't help. @pjc50, I added a few photos to my main question.

Comment: You have a 10 uF decoupling capacitor in your schematic, but I don't see it in the photos. This capacitor should be placed as close as possible to the 4060.

Comment: Well, I tried adding the decoupling capacitor, and tried addind a 10K resistor to Q0. Nothing worked, however...

Answer (score 6):

Your plug type proto board adds capacitance to each node of the circuit that is greatly reduced when you attempt to duplicate the circuit onto the perf board. It is likely that the 15pF capacitors that you show on either side of the crystal may not be the correct capacitance in the perf board version of the circuit. You could try increasing the values to 18pF and then 22pF to see if either change would get your oscillator to settle down and operate at 32.768kHz as you expect it to. It may even be necessary to try 27pF or 30pF as well and it may even be necessary to use different values at each side of the crystal.

Answer (score 4):

the net load capacitor's value is too small for 32kHz crystal.
since the breadboard has big stray capacitance, it is larger than perfboard. when you setup the circuit on breadboard, the stray capacitance will adding into load capacitor, this will make circuit running normally.

try to use 22pF or 33pF replace the two capacitor.

Answer (score 2):

This chip has 3 pins that are part of the oscillator circuit. The correct way to connect a crystal is pins 10 and 11 (from the intersil datasheet):

[image]

As far as I can see from your diagram and photo you are using pins 9 and 11.

Comment: Actually, I'm using pins 10 and 11... :( The pin 9 has some soldering on it, but it's just to hold the socket.

Comment: The circuit 'diagram' at least suggests otherwise. But if you are sure I withdraw my case.